# apt-get error on VirtualBox Ubuntu. E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component) E: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-20.04, apt-get

I am using *Ubuntu 20.04* with *Virtualbox* on a Windows PC.
I am trying to install libraries or simply update using `apt-get` by using:

```bash
 sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev

 sudo apt-get update

 apt-get update
```

but they all give this error:

```
E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)

E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Line 58 in my `sources.list` is:

```bash
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian contrib
```

I am connected to the internet and I have disabled the firewall using
`$ sudo ufw disable`

I've seen other people have fixed their problem by changing the line that gives them an error but it is not the same as mine and I don't have enough experience to know what to change. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

this will fix it:

```
sed -i '/download.virtualbox.org/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: This worked thank you! At first I was getting 'permission denied' but I just added sudo in front of sed and it went through.

Comment: sure, you need superuser access to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`. `sudo` is also needed for the second command if you run it as an usual user

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not Linux expert .

E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
The error occur when you have install wrong package on you Os system.
To solve it open /etc/apt/sources.list with nano or gedit and remove the specific line.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

By the end update package.

```
sudo apt-get update
```